# Azure SignalR with multiple clients

Tags: .net, azure, azure-signalr

In my existing application I have an .NET API and a .NET Web Application and some Azure Web Jobs.

I want the Web Application to be listening to messages that should be broadcasted either by the API or per the Azure Web Jobs.

I am a but confused in terms of architecture as I do not know how to use the Azure SignalR Service.

When I broadcast messages from the API or Web jobs what kind of implementation I need to use in the client web application to be able to listen to them ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to accomplish this by creating a ASP .NET Web Api and made that application my signalR one.

Every client or server connects to this application to either send or receive messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Azure SignalR Service and Azure Functions.

All you need to do is send messages to the Azure Functions, which will send it to SignalR who will broadcast to listeners.

Here's a sample showing how to use Azure Functions + SignalR service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config